# R and ggplot2: Make line graph of sum of value for three categorical variables over time

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to figure out how to do something with `ggplot2` and `R` that seems like it should be **really** simple. It's so simple... that I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it. I'm *sure* the answer is staring me in the face in the ggplot documentation, but I can't... find it. So. I'm here.

I frequently have datasets a lot like this:

```
tdf <- data.frame('datetime' = seq(from=as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 00:00:00'), 
             to=as.POSIXct('2012-01-31 23:59:59'), by=1))
tdf$variable <- rep(c('a','b','c'), length.out=length(tdf$datetime))
tdf$value <- sample(1:10, length(tdf$datetime), replace=T)
> head(tdf)
             datetime variable value
1 2012-01-01 00:00:00        a     7
2 2012-01-01 00:00:01        b     3
3 2012-01-01 00:00:02        c     7
4 2012-01-01 00:00:03        a     8
5 2012-01-01 00:00:04        b     2
6 2012-01-01 00:00:05        c     3
```

That is: I have a categorical variable (a factor), a value for that variable, and a timestamp at which said observation was recorded. I want to plot the sum of the value, for each categorical variable, for a given time "bucket" -- preferably using `ggplot2`. I would like to do it without having to pre-aggregate it before I visualize it -- that is, I really want the flexibility of leaving the dataset as it is and passing the arguments to `ggplot2` to aggregate it at on time. And yet, I'm *completely* flummoxed. The documentation on `geom_line` says to use `stat='identity'` to get sum of value, but once I've done that I can no longer define any kind of bin. If I use `stat_summary`, I frequently don't get a plot back at all. The closest I've gotten is:

```
tdf$variable <- factor(tdf$variable)

vis <- ggplot(tdf, aes(x=datetime, y=value, color=variable))
vis <- vis + geom_line(stat='identity')
vis <- vis + scale_x_datetime()
```

...which at least prints a plot, with a line corresponding to the values of each factor... by second. I cannot get it to `bin` the `sum(value)` operation for, say, an hour or a day or a week without doing a bunch of work to pre-aggregate the data.

Help?

**Edit**: Apologies to anyone whose R session choked on this test data. I've cut it back.

Comment: Have you considered using [stat_function](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/stat_function.html)? It would smooth the data rather than bin it, but that would probably actually work better for your purposes (no sharp transitions between bins)

Comment: (-1) you should really consider providing "smaller" data for testing. You killed my R session.

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- haven't looked at that one -- I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @Arun -- apologies. I've tightened it down.

Comment: @DavidRobinson okay, I'm pretty much stumped with stat_function; I'm beginning to think I just don't understand how the `ggplot2` docs are written. Any chance you could provide an example?

Comment: @Gastove, there's only one observation at each `datetime` and `variable` in your case... Is it this way? Or should I test with an example where for the same `datetime` you can have multiple identical `variable` values..? If not, I don't think this makes sense.. as to what `value` you want to aggregate and sum.. do you follow me?

Comment: @Arun -- for a given `variable`, there can only be one `value` for a given `datetime` -- that's correct. There _can_ be an observation of each `variable` at a given `datetime`, but each `datetime-variable` pair will be unique, and have a value. I think I followed you? Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I think this is what you want. I've cut down your dataset dramatically, the posted one is waaaay to big for a testing this stuff out.

```
tdf <- data.frame('datetime' = seq(from=as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 00:00:00'), to=as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 00:10:59'), by=1))
tdf$variable <- rep(c('a','b','c'), length.out=length(tdf$datetime))
tdf$value <- sample(1:10, length(tdf$datetime), replace=T)
tdf$variable <- factor(tdf$variable)

vis2 <- ggplot(tdf, aes(datetime, color=variable)) + 
geom_bar(binwidth=5,aes(weight=value),position="dodge") + 
scale_x_datetime(limits=c(min(tdf$datetime), max(tdf$datetime)))
```

`geom_bar` uses `stat_bin` so you can change your bins. By default it gets teh counts, but if you want the sum, you can add the `weight` argument in `aes()`. Let me know if this is not answering your question.

BTW, with the way this specific data is setup, is would probably make sense to separate your variables, using something like `facet`, ie:

```
vis2 <- ggplot(tdf, aes(datetime, fill=variable)) + 
geom_bar(binwidth=100,aes(weight=value),position="dodge") + 
scale_x_datetime(limits=c(min(tdf$datetime), max(tdf$datetime))) + 
facet_wrap(~variable)
```

Otherwise it might look like the variable are across different time bins.

Comment: A question: what does `binwidth` mean in this context? Seconds? Minutes? Is there a way to assign a particular temporal value to `binwidth`? Good point about faceting -- that's definitely something I've been looking at doing.

Comment: It is seconds in this example, because that is how your data is broken down in this example. If you had an observation every minute, it would be minutes.

Comment: Okay. The follow-up question then is, does `binwidth=5` mean 'width of 5 seconds,' or 'width of 5 observations?' Is there a way to bin by a set amount of time?

Comment: `binwidth=5` means width of 5 seconds. You can check by doing `binwidth=60`, and you'll see that it's broken at each minute.

Comment: Yep, this works great. Thanks very much! I do wish there was a way to do this with a line chart, but this... is so much better than what I had before.

Comment: I think if you want a line chart you just need to do a summary dataframe first. That's what I would do in this case, I think. Basically there are some geoms in ggplot that can use `stat_bin` and some that can't. If you want to use one that can't, you need to do the binning manually.